# What are the cause of warnings in latest CRAN check?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, cran, r-package

Previously everything was ok. But after the recent `CRAN` checks, many warnings are encountered. Here it is

```
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-clang/RcppParallel/include/tbb/task.h:721:30:
runtime error: member call on address 0x7fd0281f3d00 which does not
point to an object of type 'tbb::internal::scheduler' 0x7fd0281f3d00:
note: object is of type
'tbb::internal::custom_schedulertbb::internal::IntelSchedulerTraits'
00 00 00 00 b8 db 86 28 d0 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 80 ef ff 27 ^~ vptr for
'tbb::internal::custom_schedulertbb::internal::IntelSchedulerTraits'
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: undefined-behavior
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-clang/RcppParallel/include/tbb/task.h:721:30
in
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-clang/RcppParallel/include/tbb/parallel_reduce.h:177:19:
runtime error: member call on address 0x7fd0281d3b40 which does not
point to an object of type 'tbb::task' 0x7fd0281d3b40: note: object
has invalid vptr 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ^~ invalid vptr SUMMARY:
AddressSanitizer: undefined-behavior
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-clang/RcppParallel/include/tbb/parallel_reduce.h:177:19
in
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-clang/RcppParallel/include/tbb/task.h:688:9:
runtime error: member call on address 0x7fd0281d3b40 which does not
point to an object of type 'tbb::task' 0x7fd0281d3b40: note: object
has invalid vptr 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ^~ invalid vptr SUMMARY:
AddressSanitizer: undefined-behavior
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-clang/RcppParallel/include/tbb/task.h:688:9
in
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-clang/RcppParallel/include/tbb/parallel_reduce.h:178:31:
runtime error: member call on address 0x7fd0281d3b40 which does not
point to an object of type 'tbb::task' 0x7fd0281d3b40: note: object
has invalid vptr 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ^~ invalid vptr SUMMARY:
AddressSanitizer: undefined-behavior
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-clang/RcppParallel/include/tbb/parallel_reduce.h:178:31
in
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-clang/RcppParallel/include/tbb/task.h:946:23:
runtime error: member call on address 0x7fd0281f3d00 which does not
point to an object of type 'tbb::internal::scheduler' 0x7fd0281f3d00:
note: object is of type
'tbb::internal::custom_schedulertbb::internal::IntelSchedulerTraits'
00 00 00 00 b8 db 86 28 d0 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 80 ef ff 27 ^~ vptr for
'tbb::internal::custom_schedulertbb::internal::IntelSchedulerTraits'
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: undefined-behavior
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-clang/RcppParallel/include/tbb/task.h:946:23
in Loading required package: diagram Loading required package: shape
Loading required package: DiagrammeR Loading required package:
survival testthat results
================================================================ OK: 87 SKIPPED: 0 FAILED: 0 There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see
them)
```

I am not a C++ expert. How one can fix these issues?
Please help so that a new version of the package can be submitted to `CRAN`.

Comment: Related to [issue RcppCore/RcppParallel#36](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppParallel/issues/36)

Comment: It means I can't fix the issue. It will be fixed automatically with TBB.